# How to get a selected item in a list box with bindings?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a wpf application in c# and my problem is now I have a Listbox with bindings and my question is how can I get the text from the textbox in the Listbox?

My Listbox XAML:

```
            <ListBox x:Name="chats_lb_friends" ItemsSource="{Binding Friends_pic}" Height="870" Width="280" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="#FF535664" FontSize="18" FontFamily="/Nextopia Launcher v.2.0;component/fonts/#Mont DEMO" FontWeight="Bold" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False" MinWidth="280" SelectionChanged="chats_lb_friends_SelectionChanged_1">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel x:Name="chats_lb_friends_stackpanel" Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Ellipse x:Name="chats_lb_friends_img" Width="25" Height="25" Stroke="{Binding status}" StrokeThickness="2">
                                <Ellipse.Fill>
                                    <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="{Binding imagePath}"/>
                                </Ellipse.Fill>
                            </Ellipse>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="chats_lb_friends_txt" Text="{Binding username}" Margin="5,0,0,0" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

What do I want:

```
ListBoxItem MyItem = chats_lb_friends.SelectedItem as ListBoxItem;
if(MyItem != null)
{
    StackPanel sp = MyItem.Content as StackPanel;
    if(sp != null && sp.Children.Count > 0)
    {
        TextBlock textBlock = sp.Children[0] as TextBlock;
        if(textBlock != null)
        {
            string text = textBlock.Text;
        }
    }
}
```

But this is not working have anyone an idea why?

Thanks in the advance and sorry for my English

Comment: What is the data source that is bound to listbox? Selected item would be the data item bound to list box item.

Comment: Friends_pic is the data source

Comment: The item from friends_pic will be the selecteditem and not listboxitem. You are trying cast selected item to listbox item which will be always null. Try casting to an item in collection friends_pic and access the username property.

Comment: For complete example check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62726953/10024696)

Comment: I but the data directly from database into the listbox

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a PersonViewModel with a public string property username.

The itemssource of your lisbox doesn't seem to be bound. But let's assume you can have a window viewmodel with 2 public properties:

```
public ObservableCollection<PersonViewModel> People {get;set;} = new ObservableCollection<PersonViewModel>()

public PersonViewModel SelectedPerson {get;set;}
```

So you can bind SelectedItem of the listBox to SelectedPerson

```
<ListBox SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPerson" ItemsSource="{Binding People}"
```

Then you can do:

```
var name = SelectedPerson.username;
```

You will also want some null checking maybe

```
var name = SelectedPerson?.username ?? "";
```

You should implement inotifypropertychanged on all viewmodels and you will also likely to want to raise notifypropertychanged from the setters of your viewmodel properties.

More about working with selected items using mvvm here:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/30564.wpf-uneventful-mvvm.aspx#Select_From_List_IndexChanged

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I have already an Itemsource Bindet for the Listbox.